# Как узнать дату , в которую был выложен файл на сервере

Tags: веб-программирование, http, веб-сервер

Есть ссылка вида www.xxx.ru/.../.../1.pdf, при переходе по которой в хроме открывается pdf файл. Можно ли как то узнать когда был выложен на сервер в данную папку этот файл?

Comment: Если бы было можно, хакеры остались бы без работы))))... Я так думаю...

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае нет, так как:

1. В самом файле не хранится время записи на диск, это аттрибуты файловой системы.
2. Http протокол не содержит полей, в которых бы содержалась информация о дате записи файла на диск, так как протокол не содержит даже понятия "файл". А оперирует он только "контентом", то есть для клиента не важно - файл был прочитан с диска или был создан на лету.

Однако, есть ряд косвенных признаков, которые могут работать с определенными серверами:

1. В http есть header [Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified). Если файл был сохранен до перезапуска web-сервера (и до сброса кешей), то в нем будет дата самого первого запроса к ресурсу.
2. Если на сервере включен "Directory Listing" (что небезопасно), то можно посмотреть, что записано на файловой системе. И в этом случае серверы (Apache, IIS) по-умолчанию выводят дополнительно аттрибуты файлов, в том числе Created/Modified Date.

Comment: а где смотреть эти заголовки, это же не ajax запросы

Comment: @heff, см. любое приложение по ключевым словам "http rest client". Например, в Chrome есть дополнение "Advanced REST client" (я именно им и пользуюсь для прямой работы с header'ами). Аналогичные дополнения/расширения есть для MS Visual Studio (в т.ч. для Code), IntelliJ IDEA. Можно сделать http вызов в Python.